# FB is not defined Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, login, facebook-api

Necesito que el usuario que mi aplicación pueda loguearse en ésta misma por medio de Facebook, haciendo clic en un botón que ya tengo especificado, pero no sé si es por la versión del SDK que no me quiere ejecutar mi código.
A continuación, pegaré mi código HTML y el JS que tengo en un archivo js aparte:

JS:

```js
/*=============================================
BOTÓN FACEBOOK
=============================================*/

$(".facebook").click(function(){

 FB.login(function(response){

  validarUsuario();

 }, {scope: 'public_profile, email'})

})

/*=============================================
VALIDAR EL INGRESO
=============================================*/

function validarUsuario(){

 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

  statusChangeCallback(response);

 })

}

/*=============================================
VALIDAMOS EL CAMBIO DE ESTADO EN FACEBOOK
=============================================*/

function statusChangeCallback(response){

 if(response.status === 'connected'){

  testApi();

 }else{

  swal({
          title: "¡ERROR!",
          text: "¡Ocurrió un error al ingresar con Facebook, vuelve a intentarlo!",
          type: "error",
          confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
          closeOnConfirm: false
       },

       function(isConfirm){
            if (isConfirm) {    
               window.location = localStorage.getItem("rutaActual");
            } 
       });

 }

}

/*=============================================
INGRESAMOS A LA API DE FACEBOOK
=============================================*/

function testApi(){

 FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture',function(response){

  if(response.email == null){

   swal({
           title: "¡ERROR!",
           text: "¡Para poder ingresar al sistema debe proporcionar la información del correo electrónico!",
           type: "error",
           confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
           closeOnConfirm: false
        },

        function(isConfirm){
             if (isConfirm) {    
                window.location = localStorage.getItem("rutaActual");
             } 
        });

  }else{

   var email = response.email;
   var nombre = response.name;
   var foto = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+response.id+"/picture?type=large";

   var datos = new FormData();
   datos.append("email", email);
   datos.append("nombre",nombre);
   datos.append("foto",foto);

   $.ajax({

    url:rutaOculta+"ajax/usuarios.ajax.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:datos,
    cache:false,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(respuesta){
     
     if(respuesta == "ok"){

      window.location = localStorage.getItem("rutaActual");
     
     }else{

      swal({
              title: "¡ERROR!",
              text: "¡El correo electrónico "+email+" ya está registrado con un método diferente a Facebook!",
              type: "error",
              confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
              closeOnConfirm: false
           },

           function(isConfirm){
                if (isConfirm) {    
                  
                 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

                   if(response.status === 'connected'){     

                    FB.logout(function(response){

                     deleteCookie("fblo_307504983059062");

                     setTimeout(function(){

                      window.location=rutaOculta+"salir";

                     },500)

                    });

                    function deleteCookie(name){

                      document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

                    }

                   }

                 })

                } 
           });

     }

    }

   })

  }

 })

}
```

```html
HTML:

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- ÉSTE ES MI BOTÓN, DONDE SE LOGUEARÁ EL USUARIO. EL EVENTO SE DISPARA POR HACERLE CLIC EN LA CLASE .facebook -->
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 facebook">
  <p><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</p>
</div>


<!-- ÉSTE ES MI ARCHIVO JS DONDE TENGO LAS FUNCIONES APARTES -->
<script src="<?php echo $url; ?>vistas/js/registroFacebook.js"></script>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'Aquí va el ID de mi Aplicacion Web',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v3.2'
    });
      
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
      
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Al darle clic en el botón "Facebook", me arroja un error en la consola que me dice: FB is not defined. (Éste código fue desarrollado hace dos años aproximandamente, cuando la versión del SDK era 2.10, ahora necesito que me corra algo similar con la v3.2) si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia o solución, estaré infinitamente agradecido, Muchas gracias.

Comment: Se sigue llamando FB? tiene acceso a FB?

Comment: Yei, se sigue llamando FB,

Answer (score 0):

En `$(".facebook").click` estás ejecutando una acción que no responderá al menos que el script de FB esté cargado **(script asíncrono)**, prueba agregando  `vistas/js/registroFacebook.js` debajo de todo los scripts declarados.

`window.fbAsyncInit` se ejecuta cuando FB está cargado asi que declarar acciones dentro de esta función sería la forma correcta de empezar usar la API de FB.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia Walter, pero lamentablemente no es la forma correcta, ya lo intenté así, pero no me funcionó de esa manera.